# Oracle - Error in trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have to use this trigger in order to check an email before its inserted in my Oracle DB. There are errors in the code but I cant find it. Anyone knows can I fix it? I know that I can use a simple constraint but at my university they want me to use this.

```
create or replace TRIGGER email_check
BEFORE INSERT 
ON CLIENTS
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
tmpVar NUMBER;
TOTCOUNT NUMBER;
FIND1 NUMBER:= 0;
FIND2 NUMBER:= 0;

BEGIN 
tmpVar:= 0;

SELECT CLIENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO tmpVar
From dual;
:NEW.CLIENT_ID := tmpVar;

FIND1 := INSTR(:NEW.EMAIL,'@',1,1);
FIND2 := INSTR(:NEW.EMAIL,'.',1,1);

IF FIND1 > 0 AND FIND2 > 0 THEN * NEW.CLIENT_ID := CLIENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL
ELSE
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,'Mail Address Problem');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax errors fixed:

- Added Missing `END` at the end
- refer as `:OLD`, `:NEW` instead of `OLD`, `NEW`
- removed `*` character present after `THEN`
- added a `;` to complete the statement inside `IF`

Other changes:

- Omitted the `select from dual` statement.
- Changed to use `CLIENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL` directly instead of make the call twice.
- removed variable `tmpVar` as it is no longer required.
- removed other variables and directly use the expressions

Try this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER email_check
BEFORE INSERT 
ON CLIENTS
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF INSTR(:NEW.EMAIL,'@',1,1) > 0 AND INSTR(:NEW.EMAIL,'.',1,1) > 0 THEN 
  :NEW.CLIENT_ID := CLIENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
ELSE
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101,'Mail Address Problem');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Yes now it works thank you ! beside my syntax errors what was the problem ? the trigger was wrong ?

Comment: @NikosL24 - I mentioned all the changes made in the answer.

Comment: Isn't `if instr(:new.email,'@',1,1) > 0 and instr(:new.email,'.',1,1) > 0` just an elaborate version of `if :new.email like '%_@_%._%'`? (This is actually more thorough, as presumably `.@` etc should be rejected.)

Comment: Ideally the OP could also come up with a more informative error message than ''Mail Address Problem', perhaps suggesting what format was expected.

Comment: You could also lose `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` as it does nothing.